# How to accurately identify blobs that are License Plates? There are 2 types of plates here and can't seem to get one algorithm to detect both types

Tags: c++, opencv

Screenshot of my LPD results on a plate (type 1) 
[image: Screenshot of my LPD results on a plate (type 1)]

I'm doing License Plate Recognition but am hung up on the Plate Detection part as plates here have 2 different types of license plates.

This is the second type of license plate
[image: This is the second type of license plate]

I can find individual plates by adjusting the width and height of the bounding rectangle but want to find a way to be able to detect both the types of license plates without having to change the values manually

I've done the equalized histogram/ binarization/ removed noise / dilated. I have tried using the rows and columns and ratio but doesn't seem to fit for all the plates. Just need help with detecting all the plates. The code below is what i have resorted to.

```
for (int j = 0; j < contours1.size(); j++) {
    BlobRect = boundingRect(contours1[j]);

    if (BlobRect.width > 150 || BlobRect.width < 80
           || BlobRect.height > 50 || BlobRect.height < 20)
        drawContours(Blob, contours1, j, black, -1, 8);
    else 
        plate = Grey(BlobRect);
}
```

For most plates this works, but for plates where the the numbers and letters are in two lines and not in one straight line, it doesn't work. Vice versa if i change the width and height.

Comment: So you don't know how to say "pass test X if either test A or B passes"?

Comment: Yes but also no. I'm fairly new to C++, I have tried using multiple ifs with different values of width and height but i think i'm doing something wrong because that doesn't seem to solve the problem. So any advice on doing it the right way would be helpful. Also, I assume there is a better way to find the plates than just using ifs to detect them.

Comment: After boundingRect, do your check by area checking, in addition to height and weight

Comment: @Meisam Thank you very much, the further filtering using area did the job. Thank you once again.